# Creating AutoCompletelistview with custom adapter

Tags: android

I wanted to change the background color and text color of autocompletetextview suggestions so I decided to go with custom adapter

Eariler I was using Custom Adapter but now I decided to override **ArrayAdapter**

```
pname.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list){
        @NonNull
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            int textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.pink);
            textView.setTextColor(textColor);

            return textView;
        }
    });
```

Problem :The list background and text color got changed but I guess I am getting something weird view Here is the image :
Still the borders are black as you can see in the image instead I wanted the whole background to be white

Look at the **borders** it still black

[image]

Comment: what do you need a custom adapter for if you just want to change background color and text color of your `ACTV`'s popup?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: why are you passing `R.layout.activity_main` as the second param for `ArrayAdapter`?